# Unity deactivating wrong children with .GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 8 child `GameObjects` inside a parent I am trying to deactivate certain childre but it is deactivating unexpected ones.

```
//Hide current guide points
Transform[] points = letters[currentLetterIndex].transform.GetChild(1).GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

for (int i = 0; i < part.drawingPoints.Length; i++)
    Debug.Log(part.drawingPoints[i]);
    points[part.drawingPoints[i]].gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

The values of `part.drawingPoints` in this case are 3 and 4. But it is deactivating point `GameObject` 7, 8

If the value of `part.drawingPoints` is 0 then it actualy deactivated the parent which is strange because I thought `points` should only contain the children

Here is the `GameObject` structure and I am trying to get the `Points`

```
Letter-a
--TracingPart
----Part
----Part
--DrawingPoints
----Point
----Point
----Point
----Point
----Point
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function GetComponentsInChildren() will return all components of type Transform including on itself and all levels of children. That means index 0 will always be parent transform. And if any of it's child contains further children, they will be included in sequence.

Here is how indexes will work in this case:

```
Transform (0)
--Child (1)
--Child (2)
-----SuChild (3)
--Child (4)
```

You should use GetChild function if you want to  keep indexes correct in immediate children of a Transform.

Try this code:

```
//Hide current guide points
Transform points = letters[currentLetterIndex].transform.GetChild(1);

for (int i = 0; i < part.drawingPoints.Length; i++)
    Debug.Log(part.drawingPoints[i]);
    points.GetChild(part.drawingPoints[i]).gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense in what I was seeing. In Javascript I could `consol.log` to see the structure. `Debug.Log` shows very little. I have updated my question. It is giving me an error. `Cannot complicity convert type UnityEngine.Transform to UnityEngine.TRansform[]` for the first line

Comment: I assume points is still of type array which could be causing that error. On first line it should be Transform instead of Transform[].